# MySQL returning -0001 as year

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I'm trying to store a date that is converted and displayed as one format (d M, Y) to the user and stored in the default format in the mysql table (yyyy-mm-dd).

I'm storing the date using the following function on each date field:

```
private function formatDate($date)
    {
        if(!empty($date))
        {
            $changeFormat = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M, yy', $date);
            $newDate = $changeFormat->format('Y-m-d');
        } else {
            return "";
        }
        return $newDate;
    }
```

and reverting it back to d M, yy with the following function:

```
private function formatDateBack($date)
    {
        if(!empty($date))
        {
            $changedFormat = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
            $newDate = $changedFormat->format('d M, Y');
        } else {
            return "";
        }
        return $newDate;
    }
```

When I use the above function to retrieve the date and show it to the user, **and the date field is empty**, I get the following date back:

```
30 Nov, -0001
```

I have a hunch that this is because of the two different year formats given to the `format()` function above in my two private functions, the first being `'d M, yy'` and the second being `'d M, Y'`. However, this is the way that I can properly change the date formats, because if I change the format to 'd M, yy' in `formatDateBack()`, I will get a date like '4 Jan, 1414'.

I don't understand why I'm getting the date `30 Nov, -0001` back, even when the date shown in the database table is 0000-00-00. I would even appreciate it if I got that back instead!

If someone can help me I would love to find a solution to this.

EDIT: my date fields data type is `date`

Comment: Don't compare `!empty($date)`, check for `$date != null`, because if the field is a string (which you'll probably get from the DB) the comparison will fail.

Comment: @AlexSiri Thanks, I will update my code for that

Comment: `$changeFormat = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M, yy', $date);` isn't there suppose to be a comma after the d, as in `('d, M, yy', $date)`

Comment: @Yisera no, doesn't have to be. my dates are formatted like 4 Jan, 2014

Comment: Alright then. Was just wondering.

Comment: @AlexSiri Actually I don't think checking to see if its null will be necessary in the formatDate function as its checking to see whether the user has entered something or not (i.e. empty or not). That function doesn't interact with the returned value of the database. for the formatDateBack function that would be a possible check though. Thank you for the contribution nonetheless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function formatDateBack($dtm) 
{       
    if(is_null($dtm) || $dtm == '0000-00-00') return 'whatEverYouLike';
    $datum = new DateTime($dtm);
    return $datum->format('d.m.Y');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I might not need the is_null() check because the date field in the table defaults to 0000-00-00. But I'll test with it to make sure. Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this result, probably, because of the time zone. If the date is null, it's being translated to `0`, which is 1 of Jan of year 0, in GMT. In a different time zone, that time changes slightly.

I can only think that you're getting 30 of Nov instead of 31 Dec because this conversions, while converting the fields, lead to some problems when the month indexes change from 0-based to 1-based.